# Printing ALL contents of a scrolling DIV

Tags: html, printing

My website needs a print option but i've been trying and googling for weeks and i can not figure it out. The site has a div on it that has a scrollbar in it. When i print, only the visible area prints.

I've tried tons of things i've found online from javascript to @media print, i can't make it work.

This is my div:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; height:814px" id="results">
<table>
...contents, some tables, text and images...
</table>
</div>
```

As soon as i remove the "overflow:scroll" printing works fine, it's the scrolling that keeps messing me up. I really need step by step hold-my-hand instructions on how to make this work.

Hope someone can help me,

Jay

Answer (score 2):

**Use this JS function:**

Printable DIV is **results**

```
function printpage()
   {
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printReport= document.getElementById('results').innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printReport;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

pay close attention to the removeInline feature, which will remove inline styles for printing.